# Elegant PL/SQL to compare two numbers with different amount of decimal places

Tags: plsql, numbers, precision

I need a function to compare two numbers so that `10.12432 = 10.124` and `10.12432 != 10.123`. That is the more accurate number needs to be rounded according to the decimal places of the less accurate one.

The following function seems to do what I need (**Edited** as per Noel's comment):

```
function eq(number_1 in number, number_2 in number) return boolean is
    string_1 varchar2(100); 
    string_2 varchar2(100); 

    num_1    number;
    num_2    number;

    len      number;
begin
    string_1 := to_char(number_1, 'FM99999999999999999999999999999.99999999999999999999999999999');
    string_2 := to_char(number_2, 'FM99999999999999999999999999999.99999999999999999999999999999');

    string_1 := regexp_replace(string_1, '.*(\..*)', '\1');
    string_2 := regexp_replace(string_2, '.*(\..*)', '\1');

    len   := least(length(string_1), length(string_2)) - 1;

    num_1 := round(number_1, len);
    num_2 := round(number_2, len);

    return num_1 = num_2;

end eq;
```

But, imho, is not the most satisfying approach. Is there a better solution, notably one without resorting to strings?

Comment: This function fails for 10.012432 and 10.0124

Comment: @Noel You're right. Thanks for pointing that out. The regular expression is wrong. I have added the `FM` to the number format and changed the regular expressions. It seems to work now.

Comment: Instead of regular expression, i would use `LENGTH (number_1 - TRUNC (number_1)) - 1` to count the no. of decimals.

Answer (score 0):

You're always going to have use strings a bit, if only to know how many decimal places there are. One solution with minimil string usage is:

```
FUNCTION eq(number_1 in number, number_2 in number) return boolean is
    dot1 NUMBER;
    dot2 NUMBER;
    min_places  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    dot1 := INSTR( number_1, '.' );
    dot2 := INSTR( number_2, '.' );
    IF( dot1 = 0 OR dot2 = 0 )
    THEN
        min_places := 0;
    ELSE
        min_places := NVL( LEAST( LENGTH( SUBSTR(number_1, dot1+1) )
                                , LENGTH( SUBSTR(number_2, dot2+1) )
                                ), 0 );
    END IF;
    RETURN ROUND( number_1, min_places ) = ROUND( number_2, min_places );
END eq;
```

Edit: Just learnt about the second parameter to round from your example. I was using `*POWER(10,min_places)` before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function are_equal(i_num1 number, i_num2 number) return number deterministic is
  l_rv number := 0;
  l_places number := 0;
begin
  l_places := least(length(trim(regexp_replace(i_num1, '[^.]+\.(.*)$', '\1'))),length(trim(regexp_replace(i_num2, '[^.]+\.(.*)$', '\1'))));
  l_rv := case when (round(i_num1,l_places) = round(i_num2,l_places))  then 1 
  else 0 end;
  return l_rv;
end;
```

Note that I'm rounding (as per your post), and returning a 1 or 0 instead of boolean (more useful imo, in contexts outside pl/sql).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have found a solution without string conversion. Shoot!

```
declare
  function find_precision(
    p_input in number
  ) return number
  is
    l_check number;
  begin
    for l_i in 0 .. 39
    loop
      l_check := round(p_input, l_i);
      -- as soon as l_check is the same number as p_input we have reached the right number of decimals
      if l_check = p_input
      then
        return l_i;
      end if;
    end loop;
    -- should never get here
    raise value_error;
  end find_precision;

  function lossy_compare(
    p_number1 in number
  , p_number2 in number
  ) return boolean
  is
    l_precision number;
  begin
    l_precision := least(find_precision(p_number1), find_precision(p_number2));
    return round(p_number1, l_precision) = round(p_number2, l_precision);
  end lossy_compare;
begin

  if lossy_compare(10.12432, 10.124)
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('equal');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('not equal');
  end if;

  if lossy_compare(10.12432, 10.123)
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('equal');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('not equal');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Please note that this code regards `10.124000` to have a precision of 3 (while it is actually 6), but that is irrelevant to solve your problem.

**EDIT**
Rethinking my last remark, this may be incorrect. What outcome would you expect when comparing 10.124000 and 10.124001? My solution would give "equal" (since it treats it essentially as comparing 10.124 with 10.124001), while one might also argue "not equal" (as the trailing 0's do add precision).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old (very old) post, but I've seen lately several questions concerning floating point values. So when I ran across this I dredge up an old routine I had for making floating point comparisons. Hopefully this will be useful to future searchers. BTW It does NOT require conversion to strings as it compares relative values.

```
create or replace function compare_float(
                            float_value_1  double precision
                          , float_value_2  double precision
                          , delta_value    double precision default 1.0e-6
                          )
 return integer
 is
 /* 
    Name:          Compare_Float
    Author:        Belayer
    Date Written:  22-Jan-2009

    Floating point number are ALWAYS estimates as there is no way to precisely a
    decimal base 10 number in binary. Therefore comparing 2 floating points of 
    for equality is a risky proposition at best. 

    While the above is true, we can at least inquire as to the difference being
    enough as to not matter and then consider the values as equal even though
    in the computed since they may not be.

    This routine implements the 'close enough' comparison to give the relative 
    magnitude relationship between 2 floating point variables.

    Parameters:
      Float_Value_1. The first of 2 floating point values to be compared. 
      Float_Value_2. The second of he 2 floating point values to be compared.
      Delta_Value.   The amount of the 2 values can differ and still be considered 
                     to be equal.  Default value 10^-6 (.000001) This value can be
                     overridden on each call to the procedure.
    Return Values:
      -1 Float_Value_1 is less than Float_Value_2.
       0 Float_Value_1 equals Float_Value_2 within specified Datla_Value.
       1 Float_Value_1 is greater than Float_Value_2.

*/ 
     delta_diff           double precision;
     compare_float_result integer;
begin
    delta_diff := float_value_1 - float_value_2;
    if abs(delta_diff) < delta_value
    then
        compare_float_result := 0;
    else 
        compare_float_result := sign(delta_diff);
    end if;    
    return compare_float_result;
end compare_float;
```

The following tests the same values with different values specified for the delta_value, the allowed difference between the values to still be considered equal. Test run with values 1.0e-6(default),1.0e-3, and 1.0e-7.

```
-- test 1.3e-6 (default)
with vals (f,s,e) as 
     ( select 10.12432,  10.124,      1  from dual union all
       select 10.124,    10.124001,  -1  from dual union all
       select 1.0000124,  1.0000120,  0  from dual union all
       select 1.000124,   1.000120,   1  from dual union all       
       select 1.11000015, 1.12000015,-1  from dual union all
       select 0.0000010,  0.00000011, 0  from dual
     ) 
select compare_float(f,s) result, e expecting
  from vals;
-- test 1.3e-3 (default)  
with vals (f,s,e) as 
     ( select 10.12432,  10.124,      0  from dual union all
       select 10.124,    10.124001,   0  from dual union all
       select 1.0000124,  1.0000120,  0  from dual union all
       select 1.000124,   1.000120,   0  from dual union all       
       select 1.11000015, 1.12000015,-1  from dual union all
       select 0.0000010,  0.00000011, 0  from dual
     ) 
select compare_float(f,s, 1.0e-3) result, e expecting
  from vals; '
-- test 1.3e-7  
with vals (f,s,e) as 
     ( select 10.12432,  10.124,      1  from dual union all
       select 10.124,    10.124001,  -1  from dual union all
       select 1.0000124,  1.0000120,  1  from dual union all
       select 1.000124,   1.000120,   1  from dual union all       
       select 1.11000015, 1.12000015,-1  from dual union all
       select 0.0000010,  0.00000011,-1  from dual
     ) 
select compare_float(f,s, 1.0e-7) result, e expecting
  from vals;
```

Well it's there is anyone wants it. Note: This routine was sourced from a much older Fortran.